# Does there exist a finite set of homogeneous polynomials (+ property) whose unique solution is equivalent to a finite sequence of naturals?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the set $\{2,3,5\}$ of natural numbers.  Letting $p = 2, q = 3, r = 5$ we have: the polynomial equations: 
$$p + q = r, \\ 
 p^2 + r = q^2 \\
 q^3 - p = r^2
$$

Each is a homogeneous polynomials such that each variable occurs only once in its expanded expression.  Is there a finite set of such polynomial equations such that the only solution is $(p,q,r) = (2,3,5)$?

Comment: $p^2+r=q^2$ is homogenous? It looks like the term $r$ has degree $1$ where the others have degree $2$. (Indeed, homogenous polynomials have that scaling solutions always yields a solution... but for non-homogenous ones, existence shouldn't be hard - for any distinct pair of solutions, some polynomial should have a root at one and not at the other and, starting with finitely many solutions...)

Comment: Since "homogeneous" is defined precisely so as to make the answer to your question "no" (see Andre Nicolas' answer), I suspect you mean something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last two equations involve non-homogeneous polynomials.  And if I understand your question, the answer is no. For if $(a,b,c)$ is a solution of an equation $P(x,y,z)=0$ where $P$ is a homogeneous polynomial, then $(ka,kb,kc)$ is also a solution for any constant $k$.